# Как из mongoDB получить все значения в некотором временном интервале?

Tags: json, mongodb, timestamp

Делаю систему, которая получает с сервера данные и сохраняет их в MongoDB. Сервер в json-ответе отдает UNIX-время и значение интересующей величины. мне нужно сохранить само значение и время. Дальше мне нужно чтобы пользователь указав начальное и конечное время получил все значения которые лежат в заданном интервале времени. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оптимально организовать хранение данных в MongoDB, чтобы потом одним запросом можно было получить все значения за интервал времени

Answer (score 1):

Представим что в переменной $time хранится текущий timestamp 
тогда документ с датой должен создаваться вот так

```
$array=array();
$array['date']=new MongoDate($time);
$array['field']="value";
```

Далее просто используйте условия `$gt` больше чем и `$lt` меньше чем.
Для того чтоб вам это сделать вам нужно знать нужные интервалы,представим что интервалы хранятся в timestamp в переменных `$from` и `$to`

Тогда нужный массив будет иметь следующий вид.

```
$condition=array('date'=>array('$gt'=>new MongoDate($from),'$lt'=>new MongoDate($to));
```